# Type refinement in Crystal from yielding blocks

Tags: crystal-lang

I was using [Enumerable#select(&block)](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.31.1/Enumerable.html#select(&block:T-%3E)-instance-method) to try to refine an Array to elements of a certain type with `arr.select { |el| el.is_a?(Bar) }` but that wasn't working.

I then saw the [Enumerable#select(type)](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.31.1/Enumerable.html#select(type:U.class)forallU-instance-method) method, and that worked: https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/7v05

But I noticed that the two definitions are quite similar in my case.

[Enumerable#select(&block)](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/0e2e1d067af09e7b1e4573a7258c433e3cf8fa17/src/enumerable.cr#L1157):

```
  def select(&block : T ->)
    ary = [] of T
    each { |e| ary << e if yield e }
    ary
  end
```

[Enumerable#select(type)](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/0e2e1d067af09e7b1e4573a7258c433e3cf8fa17/src/enumerable.cr#L1171)

```
  def select(type : U.class) forall U
    ary = [] of U
    each { |e| ary << e if e.is_a?(U) }
    ary
  end
```

Is there a way to let the compiler know that the select block is refining the type of the elements (maybe by adding a type to the block somehow)? Or is there a reason the compiler can't know about what the block is asserting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the array needs to be created with the right type. So the core difference of the two methods is:

```
ary = [] of T
```

where `T` is the type argument of the `Enumerable` you invoke select on, versus

```
ary = [] of U
```

where `U` is the type argument specific to this method (`forall U`).

So to do what you want, we would need to know that the block is filtering the elements, but that's in no way encoded in the blocks type. It only has a list of argument types and a return type. However, we could certainly combine the two methods into something like:

```
module Enumerable(T)
  def select(type : U.class) forall U
    ary = [] of U
    each { |e| ary << e if yield e if e.is_a? U }
    ary
  end
end
```